# Malicious Exit Nodes in network sensor

Tags: configuration, attacks

I run an onion pi (a wireless router that redirects all of my traffic over tor, here's a [how to](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview))

Anyways I installed maltrail on my onion pi to see what's going on; found these exit nodes scanning my ports on my onion pi every day.  Just want to warn the community.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/878e28fbe116f92ceac3e8baaeb2c1f3

Answer (score 1):

These aren't scanning your ports, these are your connections to the Tor network. This is your Pi recording that *it* is connecting *to them*.

I think this should serve as an example of why blacklisting, especially without knowledge, is harmful.

These are your guards, that's why only 3 appear and the ports on their side are always the same. This log shows *you* making *outbound* connections *to* the tor network.

Comment: How often are the guards rotated then?  The Tor daemon will rotate guards even when I'm not using the pi?